How can I check the size of the file uploaded via the form?
I have a simple form on the website:
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrfInput() }}
{{ actionInput('families/families/start') }}

<input type="file" name="img" value="">

<input type="submit" value="go">
</form>

And there is a controller:
<?php
namespace modules\families\controllers;

use Craft;
use craft\web\Controller;
use craft\elements\Asset;
use craft\helpers\Assets;
use craft\web\UploadedFile;
use craft\elements\Entry;

class FamiliesController extends Controller
{

    protected array|bool|int $allowAnonymous = true;

    public function actionStart() {

        $uploadedFile = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('img');
        $tempPath = $uploadedFile->saveAsTempFile();

        $volume = Craft::$app->getVolumes()->getVolumeByHandle('uploads');
        $folder = Craft::$app->getAssets()->ensureFolderByFullPathAndVolume('family-photos', $volume, false);

        $asset = new Asset();
        $asset->newFolderId = $folder->id;
        $asset->volumeId = $volume->id;
        $asset->tempFilePath = $tempPath;
        $asset->setFilename(Assets::prepareAssetName($uploadedFile->name)); 
        $asset->avoidFilenameConflicts = true;
        $asset->setScenario(Asset::SCENARIO_CREATE);

        Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($asset);


    }
}

How can I check the uploaded file for its weight and notify the user that his file is too large? I would not like to allow users to upload files that weigh more than 2 megabytes

You can check the size property on the UploadedFile instance.
$limit = 2_097_152;
if ($uploadedFile->size > $limit) {
    // abort and return an error message
}


And in my case, how can I display an error message (that the file is too heavy)? I have two checks planned before successfully adding (1. checking for the weight of the photo. 2. Unique name). There is a condition for the weight of the file, and a condition for checking the uniqueness of the name, too. But how do I show the error to the user? How to return an error message?

By the way, your solution doesn't work for some reason. I set $limit = 524288; But the file weighing 1.5 megabytes was uploaded to the family-photos directory anyway

But no! It's okay! The condition works. I just didn't understand why you put "_" in the limit

I found such a construction in the documentation: if (!$success) { Craft::error('The file size is too large!', METHOD); }
But for some reason, an error message is not displayed on the site in case of a large file weight. Is there something you need to specify in the html form?

I believe that this should be inserted into the template: {% macro errorList(errors) %}{% if errors %}{{ ul(errors, {class: 'errors'}) }}{% endif %}{% endmacro %}
I tried to do this, but it does not output an error

i create a new question with my problem with error messages: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/41808/how-can-i-display-a-message-to-the-user-that-the-field-is-filled-in-incorrectly

@Dimi The underscore is just a numeric separator to improve readability. See https://php.watch/versions/7.4/underscore_numeric_separator

@Dimi Craft::error() will log errors to the logs, but not output anything on the page. For this, you need to add an error on the model you're creating (in this case the $family entry), then pass that model back to the template. Then use family.getErrors() in Twig to show all the errors to the user.

I have created a separate issue about error messages. Could you write a solution there. I just didn't quite understand where to add what. The example is easier to remember. The question is here: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/41808/how-can-i-display-a-message-to-the-user-that-the-field-is-filled-in-incorrectly

need easy example)
